# how can I exit a tkinter window after changing images?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm trying to make a little battle scene using Tkinter, the code is supposed to change the image, wait a couple of seconds, then exit the Tkinter window. The code I have just makes a little pause when the button to change images is pressed. I'm still a beginner and some concepts are hard for me to grasp.
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self, main):

        # canvas for image
        self.canvas = Canvas(main, width=660, height=440)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # images
        self.my_images = []
        self.my_images.append(PhotoImage(file = "att1.gif"))
        self.my_images.append(PhotoImage(file = "att2.gif"))
        self.my_image_number = 0
        # set first image on canvas
        self.image_on_canvas = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = self.my_images[self.my_image_number])

        # button to change image
        self.button = Button(main, text="FIGHT", command=self.onButton)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    #----------------

    def onButton(self):

        # next image
        self.my_image_number = 1
        if self.my_image_number == 1:
            time.sleep(2)
            root.quit()
        # change image
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_on_canvas, image = self.my_images[self.my_image_number])

root = Tk()
MainWindow(root)

root.mainloop()
```

some of this code is borrowed, I tried to alter it to fit my purpose

Comment: what is a problem/question ? Do you get error message ? Show it in question ?

Comment: use `root.destroy()`

Answer (score 1):

The image is not changed because `time.sleep(2)` blocks tkinter update.  After the sleep, tkinter quit and so the image is not updated.

Since you have only 2 images and you want to exit the tkinter window 2 seconds after the change of image, try:

```
def onButton(self):
    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_on_canvas, image=self.my_images[1])
    root.after(2000, root.destroy) # close root window after 2 seconds
```